# Carregando RenderAction dentro de _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para carregar dados de uma `model` dentro no meu `_Layout`?
Possuo um layout padrão para todas as `views` do meu projeto onde neste layout encontra-se a `div` onde fica a foto de usuário que está na minha aplicação no momento, sendo assim eu teria que trabalhar com 2 `models` ao mesmo tempo, uma para pegar a foto e nome do usuário e a outra das funcionalidades do sistema.

Na `div` onde fica a foto do usuário está assim:

```
<div class="user-img-div user-basic basic-perfil-borda">
    <img src="/Content/NewTheme/img/user.png" class="img-thumbnail" />

    <div class="inner-text">
        Jhon Deo Alex 
        <br />
        <small>Last Login : 2 Weeks Ago </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou realizando essa alteração para tentar passar a foto do usuário no momento em que a `_layout` for chamada:

```
<div class="user-img-div user-basic basic-perfil-borda">
    <img src="@Html.RenderAction("Partial1","Perfil")" class="img-thumbnail" />

    <div class="inner-text">
        Jhon Deo Alex 
        <br />
        <small>Last Login : 2 Weeks Ago </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PerfilController**

```
using IntranetCBL.Models.Persistencia;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IntranetCBL.Controllers
{
    public class PerfilController : Controller
    {
        Usuarios user = new Usuarios();
        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        // GET: /Perfil/
        public ActionResult Partial1()

        {

            var imagemlogo = db.usuarios.Where(p => p.Id == 1);
            user.UrlImg = imagemlogo.ToString();
            return View(user.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Partial1.cshtml:**

```
@model IntranetCBL.Usuarios


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.UrlImg
}
@{ Layout = null; }
<h1>teste</h2>
```

Minha aplicação iniciará pela **HomeController**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    DataContext db = new DataContext();
    CRUD cru = new CRUD();

    public ViewResult Index(int? pagina) {
        int tamanhoPagina = 3;
        int numeroPagina = pagina ?? 1;
        return View(db.avisos.OrderByDescending(p=> p.Id).ToPagedList(numeroPagina,tamanhoPagina));
    }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<IntranetCBL.Avisos>
@using PagedList.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @*<div class="container-fluid">*@
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>@item.Titulo</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @item.Texto
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                       <img src="@item.UrlImg" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        Autor: @item.usuario.Nome
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                       @item.DataAviso
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    @*</div>*@

}</br>
Pagína: @Model.PageNumber de @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { pagina = page}))
```

Comment: Você pode usar partial view.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas consegui achar a resposta para o meu problema, link para a solução https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/564e5e90-8277-4b1d-a23f-1f8ff16f4497/carregando-renderaction-dentro-de-layout?forum=mvcpt

Comment: obrigado por sua dica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`@Html.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx).

Atenção! Cuidado ao trabalhar com `@Html.Action`. Códigos podem entrar em *loop* ou parar a aplicação inteira se forem escritos de maneira errada.

Algumas dicas:

## 1: `Controller` comum

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    ...
}
```

## 2: [`[ChildActionOnly]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DadosUsuario()
    {
        ...
        return PartialView("_DadosUsuario", umViewModelComAFoto);
    }
}
```

## 3. Não use `async` na Action

O ASP.NET MVC5 não trabalha bem com `async` no caso de *Child Actions*. Use o tradicional método síncrono.